# How to use $(this) in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, this

I've made a small trivial script, where I'm checking if the class exists and then applying the logic.

Here it is:

```
if($('h3').is('.ui-accordion-header-active')){
   $('h3').css('background', 'red');
}
else {
    $('h3').css('background', 'black');
}
```

as you can see it is very simple. Now, lets say I have multiple `h3` elements on the page and I want to make browser know which one has the `class` applied. I have tried placing `$(this)` but that didn't do much. Of course, I can assign the `ID` and target the element by `IDs`, but I don't want to do that.

How can I make it more dynamic, so that `$(this)` can be used or something like `$('h3' > this)`?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using .is already for this and that isn't the issue here.

Comment: What's the point of this script? Just use CSS: `h3.ui-accordion-header-active { color: red; }`

Comment: you need to loop through, using something like $("h3").each

Comment: `$('h3.ui-accordion-header-active').css('background', 'red')` and `$('h3').not('ui-accordion-header-active').css('background', 'black')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I'm aware of that, the point is to see all the ways this can be achieved. :)

Comment: Do as @RoryMcCrossan said.

Comment: @eric.dummy if this is just a learning exercise then fair enough - in that case you just need an `each()` loop, as per @Satpal's answer

Comment: Write an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks mate.

Comment: Possibly off-topic because the question (including the comment) is not trying to solve a specific problem but merely wants to discuss the many ways something can be achieved.

Comment: @Satpal: If you undelete your answer, I'll delete my CW answer. I didn't realize you'd answered and deleted pretty much what I was writing...

Comment: @Fran, this isn't off-topic, this is my actual problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Rory pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546258/how-to-use-this-in-this-example/41546367#comment70297145_41546258), this is what CSS is for.

But [you've said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546258/how-to-use-this-in-this-example/41546367#comment70297230_41546258) you want to do it in JavaScript with jQuery, you'd use an `each` loop in the general case, or a `css` loop in this specific case:

The general case:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('.ui-accordion-header-active')) {
        $this.css('background', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $this.css('background', 'black');
    }
});
```

...which can also be rather more simply written:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('background', $this.is('.ui-accordion-header-active') ? 'red' : 'black');
});
```

But since we're setting a property with `css`, we can use the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) function's ability to call a callback:

```
$('h3').css('background', function() {
    return $(this).is('.ui-accordion-header-active') ? 'red' : 'black';
});
```

Also, `$this.is('.some-class')` can more efficiently be written `$this.hasClass('some-class')` (avoids firing up a full selector matching engine).

In fact, on modern browser, we can be even more efficient by avoiding `$(this)` entirely using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
$('h3').css('background', function() {
    return this.classList.contains('ui-accordion-header-active') ? 'red' : 'black';
});
```

Comment: maybe you should change the variable name from `h3` to something like `current_h3` to avoid confusion

Comment: @elementzero23 I normally use `$this` but thought `h3` would be clearer. Clearly not! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: I never knew that `hasClass('class')` is more effective than `.is('.class')`. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @eric.dummy: I'll admit it: I didn't **know** it is. I just knew that the problem it solves is much simpler. Solving a simpler problem is generally less work than solving a broader more complex one. And indeed, that's the case here: https://jsperf.com/is-vs-hasclass3

Comment: That's neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out - CSS is the required answer here

```
h3{background:black}
.ui-accordion-header-active{background:red}
```

This has to be much faster than any jvascript / jquery solution but if you wanted to do it with jQuery - you don't need to iterate over anything - simply use the selector as follows:

```
 $('.ui-accordion-header-active').css('background', 'red');
```

You should still set the h3 background as the css base and then the active class will overide it for the active link:

```
h3{background:black}
```

```css
h3{background:black;color:white}
.ui-accordion-header-active{background:red}
```

```html
<h3>H3 test</h3>
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header-active">H3 ui-accordion-header-active test</h3>
```